# What's wrong with this SQL JOIN? It makes my Android App crash

Tags: android, sqlite, join

```
SELECT
tblAlarmSetup.ASID AS A,
tblContact.CID AS B,
tblContact.Contact AS C,
tblSubject.SubID AS D,
tblSubject.Subject AS E,
tblAlarmSetup.IsActive AS F
FROM tblSubject
INNER JOIN (tblContact INNER JOIN tblAlarmSetup ON
tblContact.CID = tblAlarmSetup.CID) 
ON tblSubject.SubID = tblAlarmSetup.SubID
WHERE tblContact.CID = 1
AND tblSubject.SubID = 2
```

What's wrong with this SQL Statement?

I tried to separately retrieve the values from tblAlarmSetup, tblContact and tblSubject without JOINs. This works...

So there must be something wrong with the join i guess.

Im running this SQL code within a SQLite database on an Android 4.4 device and it makes the app crash. On 6.0 it doesn't crash and retrieves the correct values, but the app minimizes at that line of code when debugging so obviously something must be wrong!

thanks in advance for the help.

edit 1: after playing around with the statement for a little i noticed i always get "syntax error", but the statement above throws following exception: "no such column: tblAlarmSetup.ASID"

How in the world can that be ??? if the following works:

```
SELECT tblAlarmSetup.ASID AS A
FROM tblAlarmSetup
WHERE tblAlarmSetup.ASID = 1

SELECT tblAlarmSetup.ASID AS A
FROM tblAlarmSetup
WHERE tblAlarmSetup.CID = 1

SELECT tblAlarmSetup.ASID AS A
FROM tblAlarmSetup
WHERE tblAlarmSetup.SubID = 2

SELECT tblAlarmSetup.ASID AS A
FROM tblAlarmSetup
WHERE tblAlarmSetup.CID = 1
AND tblAlarmSetup.SubID = 2
```

Comment: single joins from tblSubject to tblAlarmSetup and tblContact to tblAlarmSetup work as well. Just the multiple joins fail

Comment: Remove the `()` around the join

Comment: like that?

FROM tblSubject
(INNER JOIN tblContact INNER JOIN tblAlarmSetup ON
tblContact.CID = tblAlarmSetup.CID) 
ON tblSubject.SubID = tblAlarmSetup.SubID

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses create something like a subquery, so the inner table names (`tblContact` and `tblAlarmSetup`) are not visible in the outer query.

Just remove the parentheses, and reorder the ON clauses appropriately:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tblContact
INNER JOIN tblAlarmSetup ON tblContact.CID = tblAlarmSetup.CID
INNER JOIN tblSubject ON tblSubject.SubID = tblAlarmSetup.SubID
...
```

or use the shorter USING clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tblContact
JOIN tblAlarmSetup USING (CID)
JOIN tblSubject USING (SubID)
...
```